# VBScript Using Computername to Name a File

Tags: vbscript

New to VBScript and having a problem grasping this concept.

This is the code:

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strCompName = WshNetwork.Computername
Wscript.Echo WshNetwork.Username >j:\strCompName.txt
WScript.Quit()
```

Basically I want to the username dumped to a text file and the text file should be named with the name of the computer.  I've tried putting the `strCompName` in quotes, single quotes, parenthesis with no success.

Comment: You're mixing [tag:batch-file] syntax with [tag:vbscript] `>` doesn't mean the same thing. If you want to save to a file will need to use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` object.

Comment: Great! Just one follow up..How can I use the computername as part of the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you can use. You need to use [**FileSystemObject**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx). The FileSystemObject is used to gain access to a computer's file system. It can create new files and access existing ones.

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strCompName = WshNetwork.Computername

'writing to file
outFile="c:\TEMP\" & strCompName & ".txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write WshNetwork.Username & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set WshNetwork = Nothing

WScript.Quit()
```

Save this in .vbs file and run and you will get a text file with computer name in **`TEMP`** folder (Change the path if you like).

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me what the purpose is of setting the objfile, objFSO, wshnetwork to nothing?

Comment: You should release reference to the object as soon as you no longer need it, it's just good a practice. However VBScript engine does this automatically when the variable that keeps the reference goes out of scope.

Comment: [When Are You Required To Set Objects To Nothing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. This code opens the file and appends it if the file exists or creates a file and writed to it if it does not exist.

```
'constants
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

'Load domain, username, & computer variables
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
sDomain = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERDOMAIN%" )
sUserName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
sComputer = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )

'Setup filesystemobject
Set oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Check to see if file exists. If exists open it forAppending
'else create file and write to it.

outFile="c:\export\" & sComputer & ".txt"
If oFSO.FileExists(outFile) Then
    Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(outFile, ForAppending, True, TristateTrue)
Else
    Set objFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
End If

'write to file
objFile.WriteLine sDomain & "\" & sUsername & " - " & Now

'clean up objects
objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oShell = Nothing
```